# Get individual field from PCollection<TableRow>

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am reading a stream of data using Apache Beam and writing to BigQuery, in `tableA`. My rows are stored in dataset of type `<TableRow>`.

Currently I am reading rows as is and writing to the table. However I would like to filter the rows based on the `timestamp` column and split data in resulting `Name` column in `FirstName` and `LastName`, before writing the data with the new schema to a new table named `tableB`

I don´t know how to get individual fields from a `PCollection` dataset and I am looking for help with the right syntax for getting a row field `Name` from my `PCollection<TableRow>`

Here´s my code:

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows =
                        transformedRows.apply("Get rows", BeamIO.getRows());
    
       /*Split a row here and name it rowsAfterColumnSplit
         --
         --
       */
        
        //Write the original set of rows
        WriteResult writeResult1 =
                        rows.apply("write rows",
                                BeamIO.getBigQueryIOWriter(schema, "tableA"));
    
        //Write rowsAfterColumnSplit with new schema
        WriteResult writeResult2 =
                        rowsAfterColumnSplit.apply("write rows after column split",
                                BeamIO.getBigQueryIOWriter(newSchema, "tableB"));
```

Here´s sample data:

```
| timestamp                    | Name           | City    |

|  2020-07-14 20:12:01.342 UTC | Karl Streisand | Berlin  | 
|  2020-07-14 22:10:10.234 UTC | Anna Karlstad  | Munich  |
```

I want to split name "Anna Karlstad" by filtering rows with timestamp after 22.00.00

Comment: Use `ParDo` or `Map`

Comment: Post sample data

Comment: Can paste the data in the question

Comment: By Split you mean - "Anna Karlstad" to `["Anna", "Karlstad"]`?

Comment: That´s right, @bigbounty. After which I am going to create a new column to save each of the elements in and update the schema. So the resulting schema would contain 5 fields i.e `timestamp, Name, FirstName, LastName, City`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here´s how you can do that:

```
PCollection<TableRow> transformedRows = rows.apply(ParDo.of(Transform.splitColumn()));
```

And here´s the `Transform` class:

```
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;

public class Transform extends DoFn<TableRow, TableRow> {

    private Transform() {
    }

    public static Transform splitColumn() {
        return new Transform();
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(@Element TableRow input, OutputReceiver<TableRow> output) {


        if(input.get("Name").toString()!=null){
            input.set("FirstName", input.get("Name").toString().split(" ")[0]);
            input.set("LastName", input.get("Name").toString().split(" ")[1]);
        }
        output.output(input);

    }
}
```

You then create a new schema with additional fields i.e `FirstName` and `LastName` and write to BigQuery using WriteResult